# How to write input values at different clock cycles in test bench of v/hdl programing?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, spartan

I am writing vhdl code for AES encryption algorithm, I have to take 128 bit data to encrypt so used 1bit input pin. for 128 bit data , I used 128 clock cycle with case statement.I have to write test bench to check the proper working of code. how to write 128 bit of data in different clock cycle in test bench.

```
if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
    count <= count + 1;
    end if;
    end process;        
    process(count,a)
begin
 case count is
 when 0 =>
    it(127)<=a;
    when 1 =>
    it(126)<=a;
    when 2 =>
    it(125)<=a;
    when 3 =>
    it(124)<=a;
    when 4 =>
    it(123)<=a;
    when 5 =>
    it(122)<=a;
    when 6 =>
    it(121)<=a;
    when 7 =>
    it(120)<=a;    .... n go for 0th bit
```

1. a in bit
2. it(128 bit signal )

Comment: If you can find a mathematical relationship between the count and the bit to write, you can eliminate that very long case statement altogether.

Comment: on the 0th count 127th bit(as i am using downto) or 0th bit(if used to) and increase count by 1 n decrease bit by 1 so on upto count 127th. and my worry how to write different ip for 128 clock cycles?

Comment: Brian is hinting that there is an easier way to index `it()`, since you already have an integer counter with a simple mathematical relationship to the order of the bits you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement a shift register to feed data in serially. In general you should use case statements only for control logic and not data flow. Treating the data vector as an addressable array is also possible but it synthesizes to a decoder which will become a timing problem at this size and isn't strictly necessary for just moving bits into place.

```vhdl
signal data : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
...
sreg: process(clock, reset)
begin
  if reset = '1' then
    data <= (others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(clock) then
    if shift_en = '1' then
      data <= data(126 downto 0) & a; -- Shift left
      -- data <= a & data(127 downto 1); -- Shift right
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

You will have to decide how to control what you do when the shift register is filled. Either implement a counter to count off 128 shifts or use another control signal that starts the next stage of processing when shifting is done.

On the test bench side you have  a lot more flexibility in how you drive signals since there are no concerns about synthesis results. You generally have two options: write synchronous processes similar in style to the DUT or use wait statements to manage the order of signalling without implementing the synchronous mechanisms needed in synthesizable code.

```vhdl
constant CPERIOD : delay_length := 10 ns;
...
stim: process is
  variable data : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
begin
  -- Initialize signal drivers
  a <= '0';
  shift_en <= '0';
  reset <= '1', '0' after CPERIOD * 2;
  wait until falling_edge(clock);
  wait for CPERIOD * 2;

  data := X"CAFEBABECAFED00D8BADFOODDEADBEEF";

  -- Shift data in from left to right
  shift_en <= '1';
  for i in data'range loop
    a <= data(i);
    wait for CPERIOD;
  end loop;
  shift_en <= '0';
  wait for CPERIOD;

  wait; -- Stop process from restarting
end process;
```

Note: Driving the stimulus on the falling edge of the clock is a lazy technique that dodges any issues with delta cycle ordering when you drive on the same edge as the receiver. It is not always appropriate to do that when you want to represent accurate timing of signals but guarantees you won't have to wrestle with the simulation engine processing events in a different order than you intended. Definitely don't do it in synthesizable code (unless you're experimenting with domino logic).

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has much more Problems than only the case statement.

I hope this will help you:

```
--very important this signal should be an integer
signal count : integer range 0 to 127;
signal it    : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);

begin
process count (clk,reset)
begin
  if (reset = '1') then
    count <= 0;
    it <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
  elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
    count <= count + 1;
    it(count) <= a; 
  end if;
end process;
```

It is even better to write count and it in different process.
I have no way to test my code here hope every think is right.

Comment: Why would you say it is better to write Count and It in different processes? Hint : I disagree, but not everyone would.

Comment: Because it's much better to debug an easier to read. Write short processes is a good design practice.